# Android not passing Value into MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, parameters

**SOLVED**:  I had the wrong url.  "rating" should have been rating**s**"

Here is my Java where I grab the two parameters (BasicNameValuePairs) and push to the PHP.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url_select = "http://www.---.com/---/insert_rating.php";

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rating", String.valueOf(ratingsDouble)));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", String.valueOf(Item)));



        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Here is my PHP where I get my Android parameters:

```
 $ratings=$_REQUEST['rating'];
 $item=$_REQUEST['item'];
```

The rest of the PHP is mostly not needed because when I hardcode a string, such as:

```
 $ratings = "5.0"
```

...it will get passed in the database; so I know that end is working (PHP to MySQL).  But when I use the $_REQUEST, it does not work.   On the Java End, I have confirmed via toast's that the two parameters are correct when they are passed into the onCreate method or in the doPostExecute method in the task.

Am I missing how to properly pass variables into PHP from Android?

Comment: change $ratings = $_POST['ratings']; and $item = $_POST['item']  it will work

Comment: I actually thought of that right after I posted this, and made the change.  Still doesn't work?

Comment: Have you added internet permission in your manifest???

Comment: I do have this permission yes.  I have tested this on my 4.0 emulator and my Galaxy Nexus device.  (sometimes I heard emulators aren't always the best to test with databases so I double checked on an actual phone).

Comment: Well make a little change and check what is d response, ResponseHandler<String> rHand = new BasicResponseHandler(); String resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  and toast the string response.

Comment: Ok, excuse my ignorance.. does this go just underneath the httPost? and the toast goes into the onPostExecute? Ive never actually used a ResponseHandler before.

Comment: I solved the issue and it was a horrible mistake.  I forgot an "s" at the end of the URL.  Doh.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and in a day or two, you'll be able to chose it as the correct answer to your question and it's perfectly valid.